# ajax autocomplete displays "undefined" when entering values in text box

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

My `.ajax` `jquery` `autocomplete` returns "undefined" when entering data in `textbox`.

I'm returning the data as an Array of strings, I see that this data is returned from database calling method, but is displayed as "undefined" when start entering a text.

This is my `.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "EmailActivation.asmx/GetIsoFromRegion",
   data: "{ 'region': '" + region + "'}",
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data){
            response($.map(data, function(item){
               return{
                   label: item.value
                   //id: item.id
               };
            }));   
    },
    error: function(response){
         alert("error: fails");
    }, 
    failure: function(response){
         alert("failure: fails" );
    }                      
});
```

What am I missing here...I'm relatively knew to .ajax so, trying to learn it little by little

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

label is what is shown in the autocomplete results.

value is what will be put in the field when you click on an autocomplete result.

You're missing out the value parameter.

make it

```
         return{
                   label: item.value
                   value : item.value
               };
```

Comment: Label is what is displayed as "undefined"

Comment: So the value must be undefined. Does your ajax response have a "value" attribute?

Comment: When putting `alert(data)` inside for `success` method, I get alert with all the returned data, separated by comma: 111111,22222,444444.

Comment: Can you post the json that is being sent back in ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: I needed to use `dataFilter: function(data) { return data; }`

Now it works